# Is it possible to set a default tax rate using Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe to create recurring subscriptions, but until now my `Products` have had their `amount` set including tax. I'm going to use `Tax Rates` for more flexibility, but a tax rate needs to be associated with each subscription.

I've created new products with the same `amount` of the corresponding old product minus the taxable percentage and setup a tax rate which is exclusive. I can write something that will hit the API to update every current active subscription with the corresponding "new" product and associate the new tax rate with the subscription. But is this necessary?

Is there a way to set a default `Tax Rate` for all current active subscriptions and/or set the default `Tax Rate` for all newly created subscriptions? (whether manually via the dashboard or via the API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t any single API call or dashboard setting that will set a Tax Rate that applies for all your active Subscriptions. Tax Rates do not broadly apply for a whole account - they can only be set on Subscriptions, Checkout Sessions, and Invoices.

You’ll need to go with the initial solution mentioned - writing some one-off code that retrieves and updates every active Subscription to the new Product and Tax Rate. Before writing your code you should probably take a quick look at https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing. Upgrading the Price for a Subscription could result in prorations or resetting your billing dates, so be sure to test it out before making changes to your live subscriptions. For your new Subscriptions you can set `default_tax_rates` (https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_tax_rates) at creation.